# why this error in java occured

Tags: java, swing, jframe

why this statement in java ( NetBeans IDE 7.2.1)

```
com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities.setWindowOpacity(this, 0.3f);
```

make the following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: The frame is decorated
    at java.awt.Frame.setOpacity(Frame.java:960)
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO! In order for people to help you with your problem consider providing some more information. Your question is too general and too ambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

From the java docs

> The opacity value is in the range [0..1]. Note that setting the opacity
> level of 0 may or may not disable the mouse event handling on this
> window. This is a platform-dependent behavior.
>
> The following conditions must be met in order to set the opacity value
> less than 1.0f:
>
> - The TRANSLUCENT translucency must be supported by the underlying
>   system
> - The window must be undecorated (see setUndecorated(boolean) and > Dialog.setUndecorated(boolean))
> - The window must not be in full-screen mode (see > GraphicsDevice.setFullScreenWindow(Window))
>
> If the requested opacity value is less than 1.0f, and any of the above conditions are
> not met, the window opacity will not change, and the
> IllegalComponentStateException will be thrown.

You have obviously not met one of the conditions, most likley the second